# Representation of Arabic characters in a string

Tags: c++, harfbuzz

I am looking to get the code for the same letter but in different positions in a string, relying on the `Arabic Presentation Forms-B reference`. For example, a string like the following:

"ممم م"

In this example, we have the same letter "م" corresponding to the code 0645. However, depending on the position in the string, it takes different glyph codes (or representation forms, or whatever name it goes by). The previous string is structured as follows (from right to left):

Position 4 → FEE3 (Initial)

Position 3 → FEE4 (Medial)

Position 2 → FEE2 (Final)

Position 1 → (space)

Position 0 → FEE1 (Isolated)

**My question is as follows:**

Does the HarfBuzz library allow this manipulation? If "Yes", which function use to accomplish that?

Comment: Is the problem with displaying the glyphs in your applications user interface or terminal the right way, or to store the encoded letters inside your application?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  It's a display issue, but to display correctly I need to have the correct code, based on the position of the letter, so i would say that I'm still in the decoding stage

Comment: If you use any Unicode encoding system, it should not matter. Lets say you want to print to the terminal, it's the terminals responsibility to make sure that combining characters (or whatever the name is) is displayed correctly. If you need to display in your own GUI, then there should be rendering libraries to handle that as well (if the UI framework itself doesn't do it, which most do), so all you provide is the properly encoded string.

Comment: And regarding the (new) HarfBuzz library, [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/harfbuzz/info) say: "It does not perform text layout or rendering, so if those functionalities are required, other libraries will have to be used, such as Pango (which incorporates HarfBuzz) for higher-level text layout, and FreeType or Anti-Grain Geometry for text rendering."

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
Displaying the result in a GUI is not my priority (for the moment), the priority is how to go from a character string (in Arabic) to a unicode representation "\uFEE3\uFEE4..."

Comment: Where does the string come from? From a terminal? From a GUI? From a file? Stored in the program itself (array or literal string)? Chances are it might already *be* in a Unicode encoding (likely UTF-8) Have you actually tried to dump all the bytes of the string in hexadecimal to see what it really is?

Comment: The rendering may be done right-to-left, but the string ought to be storing the characters in start-to-finish order, and not in "backwards" left-to-right order (so that they get rendered as-if right-to-left).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude At the moment I'm only working with literal strings, but that's not the problem, the problem is whether or not I can convert each character to some form of representation (\u....) using harfbuzz, and to answer your question, the hexadecimal format is just a way to get the isolated shape, which I used to get the other representations based on their position and display everything in a SFML program, and it's not 100% accurate !

Comment: Running `hb-shape  /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Arial.ttf -u "0645 0645 0645 0020 0645"` produces `[uni0645=4+692|space=3+569|uni0645=2+692|uni0645.init=1+807|uni0645.init=0+807]`, where "692" and "807" are glyph indices in the fonts. Not sure if you can get at the actual unicode characters though...